# Probability of $3$ questions

Tags: probability

"A boy answers three questions. If one mark is given to each correct answer and the probability that he answered a question correctly is $0.6$, find the probability that he gets no marks."

How to do this question$?$

Comment: Is there negative marks for wrong answers?

Comment: "the probability that he answered a question correctly is 0.6". It is not clear what you mean.

Comment: No negative marks for wrong answer

Answer (score 4):

Considering there are no negative marks, 
probability that the boy gets no marks 
= probability that the boy gives all answers wrong 
= $(1-0.6)^3=0.4^3 = 0.064$

since each of the events of answering a question are independent.

Comment: Yes, it is a multiple choice questions there are four choices
A. 0.784
B. 0.064
C. 0.216
D. 0